"OSError: Chromium downloadable not found at" when using requests_html module in python
I'm using requests_html module in python to render web pages dynamically. However, I've been facing an issue with chromium download when render method is used (see below code snippet):
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render(timeout=20)

The error shown is: "OSError: Chromium downloadable not found at https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1181205/chrome-win.zip: Received NoSuchKeyThe specified key does not exist.No such object: chromium-browser-snapshots/Win_x64/1181205/chrome-win.zip"

I've tried to download other versions of requests_html module but I failed.
I tried to look out for possibilities to include custom executable path but I coudn't find any.

Please let me know if there's a solution to this.

Ok, under the hood, requests_html use pyppeteer... By following theses steps, you could ignore this "error"...

Download Chromium manually: Get version 1181217 from Chromium snapshots. It's a little bit more recent but you could expect the same thing to happens.

Extract to Expected Directory: Unzip it to:
%USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/local-chromium/1181205/chrome-win/

Rename the folder to 1181205 (even though it’s actually version 1181217) to match what pyppeteer expects.

requests_html will detect the existing chrome.exe and skip downloading.


This bypasses the download error by mimicking the path pyppeteer expects without changing any code.
Furthermore, I recommend you to not use requests_html anymore, and switch so something like playright, who is more recent...

The requests_html module uses pyppeteer to handle its web automation. For whatever reason, the default executable url that pyppeteer downloads chromium from is no longer working - it now requires a key. Normally, you'd be able to specify an executable path for pyppeteer to use but as you can see below, requests_html doesn't give any option for you to specify your own executablePath argument to pyppeteer.launch.
Part of the BaseSession class in requests_html
class BaseSession(requests.Session):
    @property
    async def browser(self):
        if not hasattr(self, "_browser"):
            self._browser = await pyppeteer.launch(ignoreHTTPSErrors=not(self.verify), headless=True, args=self.__browser_args)

        return self._browser

The best thing to do would be to post a new issue on the requests_html github and ask them to allow you to pass your own executable path when creating a Session.
Alternatively, you could switch to using pyppeteer directly rather than through requests_html. This will give you full control over the Chromium executable path and other configuration options.
Here’s a basic example of how to use pyppeteer itself to render a webpage:
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def render_page(url):

    browser = await launch(
        headless=True,
        executablePath='/path/to/your/chromium')

    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)

    content = await page.content()
    await browser.close()

    return content

# Run the function and fetch the page content
rendered_html = asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
    render_page("https://www.google.com"))
print(rendered_html)

In this case you'd replace '/path/to/your/chromium' with with path to a locally installed chrome or chromium binary. You can download one from the chromium website.
